# How to randomly fill in 10% 2 dimensional array with int = 1?

Tags: java, arrays

I have little problem , im starting learn java .
I need to create 2dimensional array , and i need fill this array in 10% only int 1 of course my code need fill this array randomly .

Need some hints how to fill in 10% .

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int maxX = 10;
    int maxY = 10;
    int[][] Arr = new int[maxX][maxY];
    Random r = new Random();
    // random ints
    for (int x = 0; x < maxX; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < maxY; y++) {
            Arr[x][y] = r.nextInt(2);
        }
    }


    // printing Arr
    for (int i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Arr[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(Arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please describe in more detail which steps you have taken so far and where exactly the problem lies? You can edit your question and to provide the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the array, take a random row and column, while the percentage is not exceeded, check if the position has 0, if yes fill it with 1.

```
    int[][] array = new int[N][N];
    int percentage = N*N/10;
    int filled = 0;
    while(filled <= percentage)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int i = rand.nextInt(N+1);
        int j = rand.nextInt(N+1);
        if(array[i][j] == 0)
        {
            filled++;
            array[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the following steps:

Suppose you need to fill an N * N array.

- Create a `List` and add to it `(N * N) / 10` 1s and `(N * N * 9) / 10` 0s. `list.addAll(Collections.nCopies(count,1 or 0))` can help you here.
- Run `Collections.shuffle` on that `List` to obtain random order.
- Iterate over the elements of the `List`. The first N elements will become the first row the the 2D array, the next N elements will become the second row of the array, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to shuffling is to pick 10% x N random positions and put a 1 (if a 0 was in the position, otherwise pick another position). In pseudo code:

```
int[][] array = new int[N][N]
apply N * N / 10 times {
  index = random(0 .. N * N)
  if array(index) = 0 then array(index) = 1
  else retry with another index
```

}

You will need to convert the index from 0 to N*N into a pair of i,j in the 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "double random = Math.random();"
And then an if to check if the variable random is less or equal to 0.1